# Github pages subpage

Tags: html, css, github-pages

I'm currently having issues publishing my subpage on github pages. The html file itself loads fine but I'm not sure exactly how to load the css and js files from the top (root?) directory. It's the portfolio html under the portfolio folder and I want it to use the css and js from the top folder
[The page](http://fpolinux.github.io/knowhowmaths/portfolio/portfolio.html) 
[The repo](http://github.com/fpolinux/knowhowmaths)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my src to the full link, i.e `https://username.github.io/repo/css/styles.css`
Instead of relative path

Answer (score 1):

Change `/css/styles.css` to either `./css/styles.css` or `css/styles.css`.

Comment: Hi there, I tried this out and it didn't work for me. It doesn't move into the parent directory